# android how to set multiple BaseAdapter into a single view

Tags: android

I want to add multiple Adapter into a view.
means horizontally adapters should set to view and we can srcoll that.
How i can do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only one adapter can be assigned to any particular view. **One-to-One relation ship between view and adapter**

Comment: Then how can i do what i want?

Comment: can you explain your problem?

Comment: Do u know pulse news reader app in android?  Just see that app. I want like that in my app. How can i do that?